# High-performance priority queue to merge many sorted runs

Tags: c++, stl, priority-queue, mergesort

I have an application to do merging of > 10,000 sorted runs on a single thread and I am currently using the C++ 11 STL::priority_queue to do the work. I wonder whether there exists some open-source priority queue code (or some other  data structure/implementation that can do merging of sorted  runs) that can outperform STL::priority_queue in a single-threaded environment (for example, designed with better cache aware). Or some report on benchmarking different priority queue implementations.

Comment: How exactly are you doing the merging? If you just want to sort them, it will almost certainly be faster to put the results in a `vector` and sort it once.

Comment: If this is part of an external sort it will surely be I/O bound anyway. A PQ is not difficult to write by hand. See Knuth or Sedgewick. @rlbond You don't appear to know what 'sorted runs' means.

Comment: Yeah I think I misread the question, chalk it up to answering SO questions in the morning. As for merging I'd agree to hand-roll the implementation only after profiling.

Comment: It's not clear from your question what the performance issue you are trying to solve is.  An interval tree may be more efficient, but your question is too vague to give an accurate answer.